# JEHA & Other Exception Handling Frameworks

Tags: java, exception

I'm looking at JEHA and it looks pretty interesting. Was wondering if anybody had ever used it before and had any thoughts on how it stacks up to other Java exception frameworks.

What I'd really like to do is come up with a standard policy for handling exceptions and then build my own exception-handling jar to be reused on all my projects.  JEHA looks pretty straight-forward and I'm not sure what value/power it really adds, and was thinking that it might just be easier to write my own framework instead of having to learn/adapt JEHA.

How does SO deal with reusable exception handling mechanisms? Is JEHA a good road to go down, or is it - like so many open source projects - obsolesced/obsolescing?

Comment: I do not have an answer but I would suggest you to take a look in [Seam Catch](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/CatchModule), that seems to approach the same problem. It can be good to look at every options :) and Catch seems to be _a bit_ more usable (it seems that JEHA does not even has a readable tutorial online).

Comment: @brandizzi - Awesome suggestion - never even heard of Seam. Now you've got me interested in the whole Seam framework as well as Catch! Thanks again.

Comment: There is a lot of interesting stuff in Seam 3. The users of the good old Seam 2 framework are a bit concerned about its future, which seems full of uncertainties, but the concepts of the new framework are promising. I suggest you to take a look at it, but note that it requires either a Java EE **6** environment or Weld in your application.

Comment: The link is broken!